# Why is my network changing without me calling the optimizer?

Tags: save, pytorch

I've got a network in a reinforcement learning program where it plays against itself and updates to improve a valuation and policy. If the game is a draw or longer than a threshold the game is thrown out and the loss is never calculated and the optimizer is never called. Still, even if it does not update it still saves the network. It does this and loads the data with these functions

```
def load_net(i):
    if not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\python\\refactor\\nets\\net{}.pth'.format(i)):
        return None
    nn = net.Net()
    nn.load_state_dict(torch.load('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\python\\refactor\\nets\\net{}.pth'.format(i)))
    nn.double()
    nn.train()
    print('loaded net {}'.format(i))
    return nn


def load_latest_net():
    i = 0
    while os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\python\\refactor\\nets\\net{}.pth'.format(i)):
        i += 1
    i -= 1
    nn = net.Net()
    nn.load_state_dict(torch.load('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\python\\refactor\\nets\\net{}.pth'.format(i)))
    nn.double()
    nn.train()
    print('loaded latest net {}'.format(i))
    return nn

def save_net_as_latest(net):
    i = 0
    while os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\python\\refactor\\nets\\net{}.pth'.format(i)):
        i += 1
    print('saving net as {}'.format(i))
    torch.save(net.state_dict(), 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\python\\refactor\\nets\\net{}.pth'.format(i))
```

If I compare the output of Networks 18 and 19, say, that have not been updated inbetween, I will get a *slightly* different result. By the order of like 4 decimal places. I have no idea why. Besides the training which im positive is not happening here there are only calls such as

```
output = model(input)
```

I may have some redundant or unnecessary .double() calls. Otherwise I'm perplexed. Here is some output that shows what im talking about

```
loaded net 31
loaded net 24
0.03457238742588508
{(256, 0): 0.1320085660843816, (256, 1): 0.137342432039808, (16384, 0): 0.17418085554435797, (16384, 1): 0.10271324890344476, (1048576, 0): 0.19074605973319944, (1048576, 1): 0.16643130291875174, (67108864, 0): 0.09657753477605639}
-0.04351635692025382
{(256, 0): 0.12781107650911216, (256, 1): 0.1366737843176031, (16384, 0): 0.17335968033226215, (16384, 1): 0.10237753363808048, (1048576, 0): 0.19300295476929272, (1048576, 1): 0.1690421767620045, (67108864, 0): 0.09773279367164493}
```

Comment: does your net have `BatchNorm` layers?

Comment: Use `network.eval()` before getting the output. Then, it will not consider the batch normalization and dropout in your network, which are to be used only during training.

Comment: @akshayk07 but he is during training, he just wants to discard an episode

Comment: thanks guys it was batch norm layers.